# Why doesn't Java complain about generic map casting?

Tags: java, generics, dictionary, casting

```
Object stringMap = new HashMap<String, String>(){{ put("1", "a"); }};
Map<Integer, String> integerMap = (Map<Integer, String>)stringMap; // Why doesn't Java throw an exception at run-time?

// I know this is not a problem if stringMap is declared as Map<String, String>.
// However, the actual code above was using Spring Bean.
// Map<Integer, String> integerMap = (Map<Integer, String>)context.getBean("map");

System.out.println(integerMap.get(1)); // prints null
System.out.println(integerMap.get("1")); // prints a
```

Q1. Why Java allows such casting at run-time?

Q2. If using bean, what is the best practice to avoid this error?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Q1. Because at run-time, all `generic` info is already stripped away, so the two `Map` types are indistinguishable for the run-time environment. The `generics` are only there to help the compiler enforce type safety. To quote the [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/generics.html):

> Generics are implemented by type erasure: generic type information is
>   present only at compile time, after which it is erased by the
>   compiler. The main advantage of this approach is that it provides
>   total interoperability between generic code and legacy code that uses
>   non-parameterized types (which are technically known as raw types).
>   The main disadvantages are that parameter type information is not
>   available at run time, and that automatically generated casts may fail
>   when interoperating with ill-behaved legacy code.

Q2. Don't use raw-typed Maps. If you have to, be really really careful when you typecast them.

Answer (score 0):

I think it doesn't complains in runtyme because of type erasure ( http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html ). In runtime there is no difference between this declarations of map.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a compiler warning on an unchecked cast. The trouble is the compiled bytecode [doesn't have any generic information](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) because of type erasure problem (which is there to ensure backwards compatibility) so, as far as the JVM is concerned, a `HashMap<anything,anything>` extends `Map<anythingelse,anythingelse>`.

As to question 2: you *were* getting a warning. Don't ignore them! ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you are fetching a Map instance from the Spring context, then there will be no way for you to maintain type safety. The Spring BeanFactory is a runtime container and doesn't have a clue as to what the generic type params of an instance are.